# Apps Script w/ Google Sheets comparing values on different columns and rows in a loop

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

**The Code:**

```
function ArrayRowCheck() {
  
  // Find the last row in the array
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("15min");
  const lastRow = sheet.getRange("C2").getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).getRow().toFixed();
  const z = sheet.getRange("C2:G" + sheet.getLastRow())
  const a = z.getValues()
  
  for (let i = lastRow - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
 
      if (a[i][1] > a[i][4]) {
        console.log("True")
       
      }else {
        console.log("False")
      }
      
    }  
  }
```

**The Problem:**

In the for loop I want to be able to repetitively compare column 1 and 4 between two rows but I'm unsure how to introduce the next row up into the loop.

**Example:**

Compare row 10 column 1 with row 9 column 4
next, compare row 9 column 4 with row 8 column 1
then, compare row 8 column 1 with row 7 column 4

until we run out of rows to compare. I need access to column 1 and 4 from every row.

Comment: I would use an object that has the two rows in an array and is indexed zero through whatever and then on the index of the loop use the modulo operator to index into your object hopefully that makes sense to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- About `Compare row 10 column 1 with row 9 column 4 next, compare row 9 column 4 with row 8 column 1 then, compare row 8 column 1 with row 7 column 4`, if you want to check columns "A" and "D", `sheet.getRange("C2:G" + sheet.getLastRow())` might be required to be `sheet.getRange("A2:D" + sheet.getLastRow())`.
- I thought that `for (let i = lastRow - 2; i >= 0; i--) {` might be `for (let i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {`.
- From `a[i][1] > a[i][4]`, the 1st index of the array is `0`. Please be careful about this.

When these points are refected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```
function ArrayRowCheck() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("15min");
  const z = sheet.getRange("A2:D" + sheet.getLastRow());
  const a = z.getValues();
  for (let i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    if (a[i][0] > a[i - 1][3]) {
      console.log("True");
    } else {
      console.log("False");
    }
  }
}
```

- In this case, the value of cell "A2" cannot be compared because of no value of "D1". So, `let i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--` is used as the condition of loop.

#### References:

- [Loops and iteration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration)
- [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Comment: this is what i was looking for. I was missing that you can subtract from i within the array element. Also, thanks for the clean up of unnecessary variables.

Answer (score 1):

You want to compare values in an array but are unsure about unsure how to introduce the next row up into the loop.

In the example, comparisons cover **four rows**:

- row 10 column 1 with row 9 column 4
- row 9 column 4 with row 8 column 1
- row 8 column 1 with row 7 column 4
- You do NOT have to introduce the other rows since they are accessible within the array value using the condition value. The initialisation statement sets `i = 3` this is because a value of "0", "1" or "2" would not enable the script to access a value four rows above any given row.
- The values in rows "above" the current row can be accessed by adjusting the array value. For example:

  - `var value1 = data[i][0] // row3 column1`
  - `var value2 = data[i-1][3] // row2, column4`

---

```
function arrayRowCheck() {
  
  // Find the last row in the array
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("15min");

  var aVals = sheet.getRange("A2:A").getValues();
  var aLast = aVals.filter(String).length;
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: Number of rows of data = "+aLast)

  // get data=
  var data = sheet.getRange(2,1,aLast,4).getValues()
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: the data range = "+sheet.getRange(2,1,aLast,4).getA1Notation())

  // loop through the data
  // must start on data row#3 (zero-based index)
  // since logic compares results for previopus two rows

  for (var i=3;i<data.length;i++){
    var value1 = data[i][0] // row3 column1
    var value2 = data[i-1][3] // row2, column4
    var value3 =  data[i-2][0] // row1 column1
    var value4 =  data[i-3][3] // row0 column4
    //Logger.log("DEBUG: i="+i+", value1 = "+value1+", value2 = "+value2+", value3 = "+value3+", value4 = "+value4)
    // Comparison #1
    if (value1 > value2) {
        //console.log("DEBUG: Comparison#1 (value1 vs value2): True")
       
      }else {
        //console.log("DEBUG: Comparison#1 (value1 vs value2): False")
      }
    // Comparison #2
    if (value2 > value3) {
        //console.log("DEBUG: Comparison#2 (value2 vs value3): True")
       
      }else {
        //console.log("DEBUG: Comparison#2 (value2 vs value3): False")
      }
    // Comparison #2
    if (value3 > value4) {
        //console.log("DEBUG: Comparison#3 (value3 vs value4): True")
       
      }else {
        //console.log("DEBUG: Comparison#3 (value3 vs value4): False")
      }
  }
}
```

---

**SAMPLE DATA**

[image: sample]

**SAMPLE RESULTS**

[image: results]